# Hibernate exception on Joining two tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

DB Tables:

```sql
student (
   stud_id int primary key,
   stud_name varchar(10)
);
    
product (
   product_id int primary key,
   product_name varchar(10),
   product_price int
);
    
user (
   stud_id int,
   product_id int,
   foreign key(product_id) references product(product_id),
   foreign key(stud_id) references student(stud_id)
);
```

SQL Query I am running:

```sql
select s.stud_name, result.tot_exp
from student s
inner join (
   select u.stud_id sid, sum(product_price) tot_exp
   from product p
   inner join user u on u.product_id = p.product_id
   group by u.stud_id order by tot_exp desc
) result on s.stud_id = result.sid
order by result.tot_exp desc;
```

Entity Class:

```java
class Product {
        
   @Id
   int product_id;
   String product_name;
   int product_price;
           
   @ManyToOne() //not accepting cascade
   @JoinTable(name="user",
      joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="stud_id") },
      inverseJoinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }
   )
   Student s;
   
   // ...
}

class Student {
    
   @Id
   int stud_id;
   String stud_name;
            
   @OneToMany//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //      @JoinTable(name="user",
    //                 joinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name="stud_id") },
    //                 inverseJoinColumns= { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }
    //                )
    //      //Initially join-table was here
    List<Product> products;

    // ...
}
```

Now my question is if I mention `@JoinTable` in the `Product` class then I am getting  exceptions but surprisingly getting correct result while executing select query but getting wrong while inserting new values to Student class.

And if I mention `@JoinTable` is the `Student` class I am not getting any error and getting result as expected. Also no issues if I insert new Student in the table.

Can anyone elucidate what's actually going on? Is it wrong to declare `@JoinTable` in the `Product` class?  Please help.

Exception:

```
  Hibernate: alter table Student_Product drop index UK_f28mdtx7chxxfked98qbllv2j
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint UK_f28mdtx7chxxfked98qbllv2j unique (products_product_id)
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint FKad7avlyg2mjh9nhnh3u64yacd foreign key (products_product_id) references Product (product_id)
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint FKkkdpc75v3wtdvoq2087lt5rjn foreign key (Student_stud_id) references Student (stud_id)
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "Apr 28, 2021 11:07:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fst]
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:44 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
    INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@daf22f0] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
    Hibernate: create table Student_Product (Student_stud_id integer not null, products_product_id integer not null) type=MyISAM
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table Student_Product (Student_stud_id integer not null, products_product_id integer not null) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Student_Product (Student_stud_id integer not null, products_product_id integer not null) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at hibernate.retry.hibernate.App.main(App.java:30)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 13 more
    
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product drop index UK_f28mdtx7chxxfked98qbllv2j
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint UK_f28mdtx7chxxfked98qbllv2j unique (products_product_id)
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint FKad7avlyg2mjh9nhnh3u64yacd foreign key (products_product_id) references Product (product_id)
    Hibernate: alter table Student_Product add constraint FKkkdpc75v3wtdvoq2087lt5rjn foreign key (Student_stud_id) references Student (stud_id)
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table Student_Product add constraint FKad7avlyg2mjh9nhnh3u64yacd foreign key (products_product_id) references Product (product_id)" via JDBC Statement
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Student_Product add constraint FKad7avlyg2mjh9nhnh3u64yacd foreign key (products_product_id) references Product (product_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at hibernate.retry.hibernate.App.main(App.java:30)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'fst.student_product' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 12 more
    
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table Student_Product add constraint FKkkdpc75v3wtdvoq2087lt5rjn foreign key (Student_stud_id) references Student (stud_id)" via JDBC Statement
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Student_Product add constraint FKkkdpc75v3wtdvoq2087lt5rjn foreign key (Student_stud_id) references Student (stud_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at hibernate.retry.hibernate.App.main(App.java:30)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'fst.student_product' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 12 more
    
    Hibernate: alter table user add constraint FKhfswe0v9qoihn3j6e8lxgdkj4 foreign key (stud_id) references Product (product_id)
    Apr 28, 2021 11:07:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table user add constraint FKhfswe0v9qoihn3j6e8lxgdkj4 foreign key (stud_id) references Product (product_id)" via JDBC Statement
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table user add constraint FKhfswe0v9qoihn3j6e8lxgdkj4 foreign key (stud_id) references Product (product_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at hibernate.retry.hibernate.App.main(App.java:30)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fst`.`#sql-1aa8_b7`, CONSTRAINT `FKhfswe0v9qoihn3j6e8lxgdkj4` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`))
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 12 more
    
    Hibernate: select s.stud_name,result.tot_exp from student s inner join
    (select u.stud_id sid, SUM(product_price) tot_exp from product p inner join user u on u.product_id=p.product_id group by u.stud_id order by tot_exp desc) result
    on s.stud_id=result.sid order by result.tot_exp desc
    Name :Austin Spending:14000
    Name :Jason Spending:9000
    Name :Kendall Spending:3500
    Name :Ramsey Spending:3000
    Name :Jeremy Spending:1500
```

Hibernate Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fst</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">fst</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="hibernate.retry.hibernate.Student"/>
        <mapping class="hibernate.retry.hibernate.Product"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [@JoinTable](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation should be used only on *the owning side of the association*, the other one being referred to as the inverse (or the `mappedBy`) side.

The correct mapping for your case should be like below:

```java
@Entity
class Product {
    
   // ...
       
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinTable(name="user",
      joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="stud_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
   )
   Student s;

   // ...
}

@Entity
class Student {

        
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "s")
   List<Product> products;
}
```

P.S. Usually join table is used for modeling [@ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) association. A common case of the [bidirectional @OneToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) association is required only one foreign key on  the owning side.

Comment: How are you deciding the "owning side of the association" ? In the  inner select query I used product id as a key to get result but in the outer select query I used student id...so who is the owing side?

Comment: I am still getting same error...only getting exception-free result if I put it in Student class rather than Product class

Comment: `How are you deciding the "owning side of the association"` - for your case it can be any one. Could you please show also your hibernate config.

Comment: I have added the cfg file and also added a question -: "if I mention #JoinTable in the Product class then I am getting exceptions but surprisingly getting correct result while executing select query but getting wrong while inserting new values to Student class.

And if I mention #JoinTable is the Student class I am not getting any error and getting result as expected. Also no issues if I insert new Student in the table"

Comment: What mysql version do you use?

Comment: As you specify database name in the jdbc [connection url](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html) , I guess you can remove this : `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">fst</property>`

Comment: MySQL 8.x.x I am removing that property

Comment: You should use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` for MySQL 8.x.x

Comment: Does these thing any how related to my question? Is it throwing exceptions due this configuration mistakes?

Comment: As I see from your stack trace `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'fst.student_product' doesn't exist` , so this is quite probable

Comment: But if I add #JoinTable in Student class why it is not throwing this exception?